# What's the software that enables lot of linux commands on windows?

Tags: windows

Like "rm,ls,grep" and other most used commands are included,

what we need to do is include the directory in the PATH environment.

Where to download it?

Answer (score 12):

You might be looking for [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), which is a Linux-like environment for Windows or something more like [Unix Utils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), which are ports of GNU utilities to Windows.

EDIT: Apparently, the download on the Unix Utils page is broken. However, if that is what you want, you can still get it from the [Sourceforge download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/).

Comment: You need to install this and then add the install path and the bin under it to the path I think

Comment: Oh yes it's "Unix Utils",but not downloadable now.http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/UnxUtils.zip.
Where can I download it?

Comment: The great thing is that even though it's closed,I can still mark it as correct answer!Haha

Comment: I gave a link to an alternate download location.

Comment: If you want up-to-date tools, see gnuwin32 http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ as mentioned below.

Answer (score 6):

cygwin is a complete environment. If you're after native tools, then look at [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: +1 Yes, gnuwin32 is better if you just want the tools and don't want to screw with the whole cygwin environment.

Answer (score 3):

[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) (Minimalist GNU for Windows)

Answer (score 2):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [unixutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) or [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)

Comment: unixutils looks like it hasn't been updated for several years.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Windows Services for UNIX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463212.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I **love** [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org). It gives you a Unix console complete with bash shell, and all your faves -- ls, rm, mv, cp, grep, tar, find, emacs, vim, svn, git, etc. When you're using it, you're **in bash** (or whatever your preferred shell is) just like a Linux box.

It gives you **searchable** command history that survives the machine being restarted.

I find its way of handling paths much more intuitive and convient than Cygwin's.